# Changing a Launch Configuration while it's running

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In this Eclipse RCP application I am making, when a new launch is made, it checks some details of the already running launches which are retrieved by `DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunches()`.

If it has certain details of its configuration the same as any of the running launches, it should stop. Currently so far, so good.

**The Issue**

What happens when I edit a LaunchConfiguration while launches of its type are still ongoing? Will that change the attributes of all the running launches' launch configurations? (I am talking about what is retrieved by: `ILaunch.getLaunchConfiguration()` )

EDIT: More details: in this case it is a hardware connection, and the hardware can only receive one ongoing concurrent connection. If the launch configuration changes, and we check all of the running launches' configurations, we will be unable to check if we're launching for the same hardware twice

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way of setting whatever generates the return of `launch.getLaunchConfiguration().isReadOnly()`, to `true`.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that changing the configuration after a separate process has been launched will have any effect on the running process.

Comment: @greg-449 After a couple of tests, that seems to be the case. The launch configuration does not change for already running ILaunch instances.

Comment: please check added details

Comment: When I call launch.getLaunchConfiguration().getAttribute(String,String) it retrieves the new value that has been changed DURING the launch.

Comment: so yeah, @greg-449 despite my common sense also dictating that, seems that it's not like that. A deep copy would need to be made, maybe that's what ILaunch.setAttribute(String,String) is for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I call `ILaunch.getLaunchConfiguration().getAttribute(String,String)` it retrieves the new value that has been changed DURING the launch.

**So, yes, if an `ILaunchConfiguration` during an active `ILaunch` has some attributes changed, if there is no deep copy made in the `ILaunch`, the changes will reflect on the running `ILaunch`.** Ugh.